# wall.search vk api от имени сообщества

Tags: vkontakte-api

Ранее метод [wall.search](https://vk.com/dev/wall.search) был общедоступным и его можно было вызывать без `access_token`, т.е. так:

> [https://api.vk.com/method/wall.search?owner_id=-138638111&query=мясо&owners_only=1&count=90&v=5.58](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.search?owner_id=-138638111&query=%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BE&owners_only=1&count=90&v=5.58)

Сейчас в ответ ошибку 8 - `Invalid request: method is unavailable without access token.`

Как я понимаю, теперь в связи с [измененниями](https://vk.com/dev/service_token) нужно передавать `access_token` и для публичных методов. Если я передаю ключ доступа к сообществу, то также ошибка:

```
User authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.
```

Comment: This method can be called by a service token. Only public data is returned.

Comment: ну так мне и нужны публичные данные сообщества (записи на стене). Но при использовании ключа доступа сообщества выдает другую ошибку.

Comment: еще раз..... ........ This method can be called by a **SERVICE TOKEN** .... **не** Community Token